# glCopyImageSubData gives me GL_INVALID_VALUE

Tags: c++, opengl

I have made a minimal code example that reproduces a bug in my game.

I'm trying to copy a region of a TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY to another one.

```cpp
u32 tex0;
glGenTextures(1, &tex0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, tex0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA8, 64, 2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, initTexData);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

u32 tex1;
glGenTextures(1, &tex1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, tex1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA8, 64, 3, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glCopyImageSubData(
    tex0, GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    tex1, GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    64, 2, 1
);
```

The texture `tex0` is initialized with some pixel data and has dimensions 64x2.

Then I create `tex1` with dimensions 64x3 and empty data.

And finally I copy the contents from `tex0` to `tex1`, but it fails in the operation.

It gives error `GL_INVALID_VALUE`. According to the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCopyImageSubData.xhtml) there are a few different causes for that error. But I have debugged it with ApiTrace and it gave some useful info:

```
major api error 1281: GL_INVALID_VALUE error generated. The y values exceeds the boundaries of the corresponding image object.
glGetError(glCopyImageSubData) = GL_INVALID_VALUE
```

The error message suggests that I'm getting out of bounds but I just don't see how. I'm copying a region of 64x2, which should fit on both textures. There must be some silly mistake I can't see myself.

If you want to see the full code: https://gist.github.com/tuket/2198c17107c513c667d7381bbb34386d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the *INVALID_VALUE* error, because the *srcHeight* argument of [`glCopyImageSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCopyImageSubData.xhtml) exceeds the boundaries of the corresponding image object.

The height of an one dimensional texture is always 1. However the depth of an on dimensional texture array can be grater than 1:

```cpp
glCopyImageSubData(
    tex0, GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    tex1, GL_TEXTURE_1D_ARRAY,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    64, 1, 2                  // height = 1, but depth = 2
);
```

Don't let [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) confuse you where to specify the layers of the one-dimensional texture array using the height argument.